# Joomla sometimes messes up URLs, probably cache involved

Tags: url, joomla, cache, bugs

Every once in while my Joomla site messes up link's URLs. For example, something like this:
http://www.sism.org/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userslist&listid=4&Itemid=123

Become like this:
http://www.sism.org/index.php/component/k2/administrator/components/com_dump/assets/css/images/stories/inrilievo/sism/htm/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userslist&listid=4&Itemid=123

The new page has the right content but there's no CSS or other linked resources.

Usually I solve the problem by deleting all the cache and turning it off and on again, which is pretty annoying. Watching the URLs the components involved seem to be K2 and Jdump.

Does any one have any clue on this?

Comment: Actually this time resetting the cache didn't solve the problem!!! Help!!!

Comment: i had to turn off cache completely to make it work! but of course it slowed the loading down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution found!

As you could see in the question, the wrong url that joomla generated has com_dump in it.

I unistalled JDump and reset the cache and now it seems to work.

I don't know if this was really the problem or it's still a cache bug and it will reappear in another manner, but for now it works.

I'll keep you updated, but in the mean time i would like some opinion about the problem!

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing, today, suddenly, it messed up urls again...
now it show e.g. this: http://www.sism.org/index.php/generale/sism/media/system/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=12&Itemid=116

Instead of this: http://www.sism.org/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=12&Itemid=116

I turned cache off again and it works...

Help!!!